# How to loop through sheet and copy some specific range

Tags: vba

So I would like my code to loop through sheets, depend on sheet name I would like to copy different range (if sheet will not be listed i want just to skip it) (lets say i know number/adress of the columns i would like to copy (number of rows might be different, depends on the orginal file i got) and i would like to copy all of these ranges one under another into sheet called check_data with additional column to the right saying from which sheet this part is comming from. I'm stuck sometimes this part of code works but it seems like it doesnt loop through the sheets.

So far i got this (but im totally new to vba)

```
Sub Copy_data()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("A")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("B")
Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("Check_data")


For Each ws In Worksheets

If ws.Name = "A" Then
ws1.Activate
ws1.Range("A1:Q1").Select
ws1.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
ws3.Select
    If ws3.Range("A1") = "" Then
       ws3.Range("A1").Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
    Else
        Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If

ElseIf ws.Name = "B" Then
ws2.Activate
ws2.Range("A1:Q1").Select
ws2.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
ws3.Select
    If ws3.Range("A1") = "" Then
        ws3.Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Else
        Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Else
End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here. Always fully specify both the workbook and worksheets with objects, and preprend methods like `Sheets` with those objects, like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

ws1 = wb.Sheets("A")
ws2 = wb.Sheets("Check_data")

ws1.Range("A1:Q1").Select
ws1.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

...and same thing when you are ready to paste, except that you need to *explicitly activate* the sheet that you are pasting into:

```
ws2.Activate

If ws2.Range("A1") = "" Then
    ws2.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Paste
Else
    Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.Paste
End If
```

Obviously, this isn't your entire code snippet rewritten, but it's the direction that you want to head in.

Comment: Hi again, so with all you advices I managed to fix my code so It works now, but I have one more issue to solve. What if, let's say I would like to copy two different ranges from sheet "B", for example not only A1:Q1, but also T1:X5. So the final code should work like It copy specific range from sheet "A" to sheet called check_data, then from sheet called "B" it should copy range A1:Q1 but also I would like it to copy from the same sheet another range, lets say T1:X5 to this check_data sheet (still under already copied ranges)

Comment: you can use Union to combine ranges.

Comment: Short documentation on Union [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2021718&seqNum=11). You could also just do two successive `Select` and `Selection.Paste` operations, but I think Union is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks all for your input, but can I manipulate this new range somehow? because right now i got this new range: https://i.imgur.com/DKtS4ET.png - and i would like to copy it to a new sheet one under another

Comment: If you require that level of control then I would just do two successive `Select` and `Selection.Paste` operations...